# Отправка POST-запроса axios (ReactJS)

Tags: reactjs, http, post, request, axios

Пытаюсь отправить POST-запрос на сервер:

```
sendDataOnServer() {
        axios.post('http://localhost/parser/api/set_bet.php',{
                market: this.props.bets.market,
                outcome: this.props.bets.type,
                odd: this.props.bets.odd,
                stake: this.state.value

        })
    }
```

Но почему-то отправляется OPTIONS-запрос, как пофиксить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `OPTIONS` отправляется браузером, чтобы проверить возможен ли кросс-доменный POST-запрос. И похоже он у вас не разрешён, поэтому POST-запроса не следует.

Разрешить кросс-доменные запросы можно указав в ответе сервера заголовок `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost`.

Comment: Сработало, но я указал `*` вместо `http://localhost`. И ещё нужно было добавить `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *`